# Exporting an array whose contents are determined by a database

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Listings component that essentially reads in a database of events that is stored using MongoDB. What I'm trying to do is create a Google Maps that has markers at each of the events' location. Right now, my code accurately retrieves the Listings and creates an array with only the coordinates of the events. However, since I have to export it to a Google Maps Component, the changes I make to my location array does not get exported correctly. How do I make sure my array with all the coordinates can get exported properly?

Here is my code for the Listings:

```
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { Box, Container } from '@mui/material';

let locArray = [];

export default function Listings({ setFeaturedPosts}) {
  const [listings, setListings] = useState(null);

  async function retrieveListings() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/getevents', {
        loc: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('location')),
        nEvents: 10,
        startdate: dayjs().startOf('day'),
        enddate: dayjs().endOf('day'),
        eventtype: null
      }, { crossdomain: true });
    
      if (res && res.status === 200) {
        setListings(res.data);
        const newLocArray = res.data.map((listing) => listing.location.coordinates);
        locArray = newLocArray;
      } else {
        alert(res.data.message);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      alert('Failed to retrieve events: ', err.message);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveListings();
  }, []);

  const updateFeaturedPost = (index, updatedPost) => {
    setFeaturedPosts((prevPosts) => {
      const newPosts = [...prevPosts];
      newPosts[index] = updatedPost;
      return newPosts;
    });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Box elevation={0} style={{ height: '70vh', overflow: 'auto' }}>
        <List>
          {listings &&
            listings.map((listing, index) => {
              const { orgname, title, date, description, startTime, endTime } = listing;
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={listing._id}>
                  <Paper elevation={4} style={{ width: '300px', p: 2, padding: '20px', marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                    <Grid>
                      {orgname}
                      {title} {date}
                      {description}
                      {startTime}
                      {endTime}
                    </Grid>
                  </Paper>
                  <Divider />
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            })}
        </List>
      </Box>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export function getlocArray() {
  return locArray;
}
```

Here is how I'm importing it in my Google Maps file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { Listings, getlocArray } from './listings';

const containerStyle = {
  width: '600px',
  height: '600px',
};

const center = {
  lat: 37.7749,
  lng: -112.4194,
};

const importedlocArray = getlocArray();

function MapsComponent() {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (importedlocArray.length > 0) {
      setMarkers(
        importedlocArray.map((location, index) => ({
          key: index,
          position: location,
        }))
      );
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="API-key">
        <GoogleMap mapContainerStyle={containerStyle} center={center} zoom={15}>

          <Marker position = {center} />

          {markers.map((marker) => (
            <Marker 
              key={marker.key} 
              position={marker.position} 
            />
          ))}
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
    </>
  );
}

export default React.memo(MapsComponent);
```